# Let $f$ be a continuous monotone function. Show that $f$ must be absolutely continuous on [0,1]

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, monotone-functions, absolute-continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous monotone function such that $f$ is differentiable everywhere on (0,1) and $f'(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. Show that $f$ must  be absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$
and construct a counter example for the case without the "monotone" condition.

My attempt:

$f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in $(0,1)$ anld continuous on (0,1), then $f'(x)$ is integrable on (0,1) and

$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f'(x) + f(0),\forall x \in [0,1]$$

Since $f$ is an indefinite integral on [0,1] hence $f$ is absolutely continuous.

I want a different approach with the direct proof using the definition and not using so many theorems.

for the counterexample I have:

$f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ and we must show that $f$ is not of bounded variation.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument for the first part is not correct. You did not use monotonicity. Assume that $f$ is monotonically increasing. Note that $f' \geq 0$ on $(0,1)$. We can write $f(x)=f(\frac 1 2)+\int_{1/2} ^{x} f'(t)\, dt$ for $x<\frac 1 2 <1$. Since LHS tends to the finite limit $f(1)$ as $ x \to 1$ it follows that $\int_{1/2}^{1} |f'(t)|\, dt=\int_{1/2}^{1} f'(t)\, dt <\infty$. Similarly, $\int_0^{1/2} |f'(t)|\, dt <\infty$. This proves that $f'$ is integrable. Now it is easy to see that $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x} f'(t)\, dt$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ from which absolute continuity follows.

For the second part consider the intervals $(\frac 1 {\frac {(2n+1)\pi} 2},\frac 1 {n\pi})$ and apply definition of absolute continuity.

Comment: Why you choose 1/2 ? and why not applying that directly to [0,x] ?

Comment: The equation $f(x) =\int_0^{x} f'(t)\, dt$ cannot be justified without monotonicity. In fact we don't even know that this integral exists. @RichardClare

Comment: Hey, I think we should have that $f(x) + f(1/2) = \int_{1/2}^{x}f'(t)dt$ ???

Comment: @RichardClare I have made some corrections in my answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you send proof $f(x) = int_0^x f’(t) dt$ that’s equality only for monotone functions?

Comment: By FTC $f(x)=f(\frac 1  2)+\int_{\frac1  2}^{x} f'(t)dt$ for $0 <x<1$. Use continuity to show that this holds even for $x =0,1$. Apply this for $x=\frac 1 2$ and subtract one equation from the other to finish. @Simurgh